# Track IR Led using EMGU CV?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have been trying to make head mounted (Infrared)IR Led light tracker using EMGU CV? I know head tracking using EMGU CV. But head mounted IR Led light tracker gives more accuracy. I want make some thing like [Head tracking with webcam](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wT1RQVioDmM&feature=related) or [FreeTrack](http://www.free-track.net/english/). Any guidelines will be appreciated>

Comment: So you want a camera to track an IR LED on someones head?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific... I know blob tracking but I want to do 3d head tracking using IR led lights like the following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wT1RQVioDmM&feature=related .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a quite solid and accurate head tracking using IR LED you should
put an IR filter on your camera sensor (if it's not already shipped with it) and then use IR threshold... once you have found a binary thresholded mask emgucv blob detection will be quite easy.

You can see an example of the suggested approach applied to a low cost PS3-Eye camera
here:

http://codelaboratories.com/forums/viewthread/444/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the answer to my comment is 'Yes, an IR LED on someone's head is tracked by a camera. I think you will find this to be a pretty easy task since the IR LED is likely the brightest object in the scene by far. You can simply use threshold and blob analysis. I think this link is a good starting place for you. http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=205

Answer (score 0):

I go with the above two answers and recommend using a IR filter.
I guess the question included **3D** stuff.

Use two LED's. Track using the above two methods. If the distance between those two led's is greater then the led's are closer to the camera else further. You can even take in account of rotation like that.

Hope this helps.